# loop values into divs in django template

Tags: django, django-templates

I have a table with 9 values. I want to loop through the table and put the results into a div structure in the template.

I tried to [cycle](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/ref/templates/builtins/) through them, but I wasn't able to put them into different divs.

The following works to put the same value in both places. How can I increment to the next group_nm?

```
{% for g in groups %}

    <div class="left1">
            <a href="/group/{{ g.group_nm }}">
        <img src="/site_media/images/groups/{{ g.group_nm }}.gif" height="125px" width="200em" />
            </a>
    <p align="center">    
        <font size="5" face="Georgia, Arial" color="maroon">
            {{ g.group_nm }}
        </font>
    </p>
    </div>

    <div class="left2">
            <a href="/group/{{ g.group_nm }} ">
        <img src="/site_media/images/groups/{{ g.group_nm }}.jpg" height="125px" width="200em" />
            </a>
    <p align="center">          
        <font size="5" face="Georgia, Arial" color="maroon">
            {{ g.group_nm }}
        </font>
    </p>         
    </div>
```

Thanks.

EDIT: I want to do this with 9 groups (eventually, in another place, I'll want to do it with an unlimited number). The above example only shows an example of 2 that are repeated.

Comment: What is expected output?

Comment: I want it to put the first group name into div class left1, and the second into left2.

Comment: Show us content of `groups` variable. What is the difference between groups?

Comment: I'm simply returning names. Like group1, group2, ... group9.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved it, but only if I know the number of rows that will be returned. This is will not work with unlimited numbers and isn't as elegant as I want, but it'll do.

I used the ifequal forloop.counter which I found in the [django google group.](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/django-users/w3jVf4vRcFY)

```
<body>
{% for g in groups %}
    {% ifequal forloop.counter 1 %}
    <div class="left1">+
            <a href="/group/{{ g.group_nm }}">
        <img src="/site_media/images/groups/{{ g.group_nm }}.gif" height="125px" width="200em" />
            </a>
    <p align="center">    
        <font size="5" face="Georgia, Arial" color="maroon">
            {{ g.group_nm }}
        </font>
    </p>
    </div>
    {% endifequal  %}
    {% ifequal forloop.counter 2 %}  
    <div class="left2">
            <a href="/group/{{ g.group_nm }} ">
        <img src="/site_media/images/groups/{{ g.group_nm }}.jpg" height="125px" width="200em" />
            </a>
    <p align="center">          
        <font size="5" face="Georgia, Arial" color="maroon">
            {{ g.group_nm }}
        </font>
    </p>         
    </div>

    {% endifequal  %}
    {% ifequal forloop.counter 3 %}  
    <div class="left3">
            <a href="/group/{{ g.group_nm }} ">
       <img src="/site_media/images/groups/{{ g.group_nm }}.gif" height="125px" width="200em" />
            </a>
    <p align="center">
        <font size="5" face="Georgia, Arial" color="maroon">
            {{ g.group_nm }}
        </font>     
    </p>            
    </div>
</div> 

    {% endifequal  %}
```

and on through all 9 groups.

Answer (score 2):

You can just use the forloop.counter value to create the class name (assuming they are named left1, left2, left3, left4, left5, etc.):

```
{% for g in groups %}
      <div class="left{{ forloop.counter }}">
         <a href="/group/{{ g.group_nm }}">
         <img src="/site_media/images/groups/{{ g.group_nm }}.gif" height="125px" width="200em" />
         </a>
         <p align="center">    
             <font size="5" face="Georgia, Arial" color="maroon">
                {{ g.group_nm }}
             </font> 
         </p>
       </div>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Thanks donarb. This is what I came up with as well.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this in template:

```
{% for g in groups %}
    {% if forloop.counter|divisibleby:"2" %}
      <div class="left1">
         <a href="/group/{{ g.group_nm }}">
         <img src="/site_media/images/groups/{{ g.group_nm }}.gif" height="125px" width="200em" />
         </a>
         <p align="center">    
             <font size="5" face="Georgia, Arial" color="maroon">
                {{ g.group_nm }}
             </font> 
         </p>
       </div>
    {% else %}
        <div class="left2">
           <a href="/group/{{ g.group_nm }} ">
              <img src="/site_media/images/groups/{{ g.group_nm }}.jpg" height="125px" width="200em" />
           </a>
           <p align="center">          
               <font size="5" face="Georgia, Arial" color="maroon">
                    {{ g.group_nm }}
               </font>
           </p>         
        </div>
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: But the divisibleby will only take 1 of the 2 values. Plus, I have nine that I want to div - what would be the divisibleby to put 1 through 9 into the proper place.

Comment: +1 for pointing me in the direction of the forloop.counter. Thanks!